# PHP MySQL - INNER JOIN: userid = part of value

Tags: php, mysql

Lets say I got this tables:

user:

```
userid       |      stuff
 777         |      bla
 888         |      bla2
 34          |      bla3
 66          |      bla4
```

visitors:

```
user_visitor |
 777_34      |
 888_34      |
 777_66      |
```

What I need:

```
SELECT
    *
    FROM
    visitors INNER JOIN user
    ON
    (the part after _ from user_visitor) = userid
    WHERE
    user_visitor LIKE '%777_%'
```

so when I parse `userid` and and `stuff` I get `34` / `bla3` and `66` / `bla4`

How could I do that? Is it even possible?

Comment: Why don't you split user_visitor to two columns like user_id and visitor_id. I think it will be very easy than what you are trying to do.

Comment: Because checking if the visitor already visited this user every time before inserting the visit or not would be more work for the server then. I will only do that when the way I want it isn't possible

Comment: Or is it possible to make the COMBO "user" and "visitor" as unique?

Comment: Yes it is possible like this. ALTER TABLE `user` ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(`userid`, `stuff`);

Comment: Can I do that in phpmyadmin? what would be the code? When you post your solution as answer and it works I'll accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you want to do,

```
SELECT l1.stuff
FROM user_1 AS l1
INNER JOIN visitors AS l2
ON l2.user_visitor LIKE concat('%',l1.userid);
```

But I suggest you should split user_visitor to two column like userid and visitorid then you can add unique index them like this

```
ALTER TABLE visitors ADD UNIQUE unique_index(userid, visitorid);
```

Then your query like this.

```
SELECT l1.stuff
FROM user_1 AS l1
INNER JOIN visitors AS l2
ON l2.visitorid = l1.userid
```

It is more efficient.
Edit: You can do these in phpmyadmin.